# Programmatically advance UIPageViewController - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

This is my first attempt at an IOS app, and I have no experience with swift, and a lot of the code is borrowed from the web and edited.

I am trying to create a set of slides. I go from the main Landing page to another View Controller, TestVC, that runs the slides. The landing page and the slides work. I can swipe back and forth. I am now trying to add a timer so that the slides auto advance every 5 or so seconds.

I believe that the code that needs to be run is:

```
pageViewController.setViewControllers(varPageVC, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

*I get an error* :

```
test.swift:31:9: Ambiguous reference to member 'pageViewController(_:viewControllerBefore:)'.
```

I do not know how to interpret this error and move forward. The error is triggered in the `test.swift`, where a timer calls a function that tries to advance the slide. Advise is appreciated. If I am doing it wrong, please point me in the appropriate direction.

The landing page has a button, that opens a `ViewController` testVC. I have 2 files, `test.swift` and `alphabetItemController.swift`. The storyboard has, in addition to the landing page `ViewController`, a `PageViewController` called alphabetPVC, a `ViewController` called alphabetVC and a `ViewController` called TestVC.

Here is the code for alphabetItemController.swift ...

```
import UIKit

class alphabetItemController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var contentImageView2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentWordPn: UILabel!

    var itemIndex: Int = 0
    var imageName: String = ""
    var wordPN: String = ""

    var tTime: Timer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        contentImageView2!.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        contentWordPn!.text = wordPN

    }

}
```

Here is the code for test.swift ...

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class testItemController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var tTime: Timer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createPageViewController()
        setupPageControl()

        tTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(changeSlide), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        //tTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(goToNextPage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }


    func changeSlide() {
        pageViewController.setViewControllers(varPageVC, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // MARK: - Variables
    private var varPageVC: UIPageViewController?


    private let contentTextWordPN = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    private let contentCount = 5 //TODO ADJUST THIS FOR EACH COLLECTION


    private func createPageViewController() {

        let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "alphabetPVC") as! UIPageViewController

        pageController.dataSource = self

        if contentCount > 0 {
            let firstController = getItemController(itemIndex: 0)!
            let startingViewControllers = [firstController]
            pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

        varPageVC = pageController
        addChildViewController(varPageVC!)
        self.view.addSubview(varPageVC!.view)
        varPageVC!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    private func setupPageControl() {
        let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
        appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    }

    func pageViewController(_ varPageVC: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as! alphabetItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getItemController(itemIndex: itemController.itemIndex-1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ varPageVC: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as! alphabetItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex+1 < contentCount {
            return getItemController(itemIndex: itemController.itemIndex+1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> alphabetItemController? {

        if itemIndex < contentCount {
            let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "alphabetVC") as! alphabetItemController

            pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
            pageItemController.imageName = "alphabet_" + String(format: "%02d", (itemIndex + 1)) //alphabet_01

            pageItemController.wordPN = contentTextWordPN[itemIndex]


            return pageItemController
        }

        return nil
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(varPageVC: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return contentCount
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(varPageVC: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func currentControllerIndex() -> Int {

        let pageItemController = self.currentController()

        if let controller = pageItemController as? alphabetItemController {
            return controller.itemIndex
        }

        return -1
    }

    func currentController() -> UIViewController? {

        if (self.varPageVC?.viewControllers?.count)! > 0 {
            return self.varPageVC?.viewControllers![0]
        }

        return nil
    }

}

extension UIPageViewController {

    func goToNextPage(animated: Bool = true) {
        guard let currentViewController = self.viewControllers?.first else { return }
        guard let nextViewController = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) else { return }
        setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: .forward, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }

    func goToPreviousPage(animated: Bool = true) {
        guard let currentViewController = self.viewControllers?.first else { return }
        guard let previousViewController = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerBefore: currentViewController) else { return }
        setViewControllers([previousViewController], direction: .reverse, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

There is even an extension `UIPageViewController`, but I do not know how to call the goToNextPage function.

Comment: At the risk of sending you off in a different direction, if your slides are pictures, you might find it easier to use a UICollectionView in paged mode. Nevertheless, you are creating an extension on UIPageViewController, so therefore you can call `pageViewController.goToNextPage`.

Comment: Furthermore, you never store `pageViewController` anywhere, which is probably why you're getting the error. Currently `createPageViewController` is creating the controller in a local variable, which therefore goes out of scope at the end of the proc.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up changing the changeSlide() function to call varPageVC?.goToNextPage()

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the `changeSlide()` function... I had the next slide function in the extension already, and only the syntax to call it was eluding me... I found some examples on SO and used them as references:

```
func changeSlide() {
    varPageVC?.goToNextPage()
}
```